# counting characters in a file in C - very basic

Tags: c, file, fgetc

This is my first time in a while working with files, and while I get the general idea, I have some problems implementing simple algorithms.

For example, I'm trying to write a code that counts number of characters in a given file. Number of letters.

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
FILE *fp;
void main()
{
    int counter=0;
    fp=fopen("G:\hellostackoverflow.txt","r");
    while(fgetc(fp)!=EOF)
        counter++;
    printf("there are %d letters", counter);
}
```

When I run it, I run into an error, something along the lines of:

Debug assertion failed!

Expression(stream!=NULL)

For information on how...

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: The obvious issue is that you need to escape the backslash in your path.

Comment: You need to check `fp != NULL` before reading from the file. If is is null, then you have failed to open the file.

Comment: The problem was indeed that the file wasn't opened, adding another backslash fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like your program is not being able to read the input file. You should always check fopen for null to detect this sort of problem

```
fp=fopen("G:\hellostackoverflow.txt","r");
if(fp == NULL){
     printf("could not open file\n");
     return 1;
}
```

My guess is that the problem is the un-escaped backslash in the pathname. Try escaping it `"G:\\hellostackoverflow.txt"` or moving your file to a different location that does not require backslashes.

Comment: It's working! Thank you! could you explain what was the issue? What does it mean "escape the backslash"?

Comment: C strings use combinations of backslashes and other characters to write down special characters. For example, `\n` is a newline character. In order to write a real backslash you need to use `\\\`.